# is it possible to filter checkout cart collection magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, collection

Actually i want to filter the checkout cart collection using custom
attributes values [using this link](https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/how-to-get-current-cart-count-in-magento2/)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteId = $objectManager-> create(‘Magento\Checkout\Model\Session’)->getQuoteId();
$cartData = $objectManager->create(‘Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository’)->get($quoteId)->getAllVisibleItems(); 
$currentItemCount = count($cartData); //Current cart quote count echo $currentItemCount;
```

Comment: what you want here please clarify

Comment: @Rakesh,Actually this code is for checkout cart collection and I want to filter this collection using custom attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$quoteId = $objectManager-> create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId();
$cartData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository')->get($quoteId)->getAllVisibleItems(); 

foreach($items as $item) {
    $item = $item->load($item->getProductId());

    if($item->getData('custom_attribute')=='SM100'){
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";   
    }


  }
```

Comment: ,i have same code but need to add filter this collection with custom attributes as like we filter addAttributeToFilter('product_type','apple')

Comment: put condition in for loop `if($item->getSku()=='SM100'){}` it is only way to do this

Comment: ,getSku is the default attribute

Comment: you can add your custom, first load product in for loop i have edit my answer

Comment: ,Magento\Catalog\Model\Product wont give current added products to the cart.

Comment: you need just `id` for load product, for current added product use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`